# Why do the views in my TableRow don't react to their weights?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I'm programming an Android app and I'm trying to show a table. My problem is, that the columns don't fill the screen, they just all stick to left.

I already tried using padding, but first I don't think that it's compatible with all display resolutions and second the columns were aligned differently when they had different content in them.

Then I read about weight and this was exactly what I wanted, giving every column a specific percentage of the width of the screen. But weights did lead to the cells sticking to the left again. They did react in no way to the weights I've set.

I program the view in xml templates and inflate them programmatically using the LayoutInflater. Then I add them to the corresponding TableRow. All that works perfectly fine, but they just don't react to the weights.

I would really appreciate your help.

EDIT: The templates refer to a style and look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/scheduleClass" />
```

And the style looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="scheduleItem" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="scheduleClass" parent="scheduleItem">
        <item name="android:layout_weight">0.2</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

There are other a few other columns, but they just have another name and another weight.

And this is how I add the views to the table:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Lesson> lessons) {
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    for(Lesson cancel : lessons) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView date = (TextView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scheduledatetemplate, null);
        date.setText(cancel.date);

        TextView classname = (TextView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scheduleclasstemplate, null);
        classname.setText(cancel.classname);

        TextView lesson = (TextView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.schedulelessontemplate, null);
        lesson.setText(cancel.lesson);

        Button details = (Button) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.detailsbuttontemplate, null);
        details.setText(R.string.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(this);

        row.addView(date);
        row.addView(classname);
        row.addView(lesson);
        row.addView(details);

        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

And this is the TableLayout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @iturki There is no layout to post, because I add the TableRows and their content programmatically, but I added the code to do that to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `android:layout_column` and `android:layout_span` attributes to your `TableRow`s

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html

See an example here:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/

UPDATE:
Ok, you'll need to set the layout_span and layout_column in each of the rows you're creating, use this addView method:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

To supply the layout params with the appropriate column and span, to make your row span to the entire table, and have the row gravity=center to make their content in the center.

Also, the table attribute `strechColumns`
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns
Might help you, as in:

```
android:strechColumns="*"
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't exactly know what you mean with that. I added the android:layout_column attribute to every column now, but they still stick to the left. And I also don't want to span my views over multiple columns.

Comment: Please post the TableLayout xml with the TableRows, so I could help you

Comment: Thank you very much, the views still don't react in any way to the weights I set but android:stretchClumns="*" leads to the result I intended.

Comment: I don't think TableLayout uses weights at all, not all layouts consider weights for sizing, for example RelativeLayout ignores them. If my answer was helpful please mark it as a solution so others could use it as well